# is there a way to extract 70% of character from a string using bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have column with Names of various length like :

```
Name      | ID
Avi       | 01
Li        | 02
Amandeep  | 03
```

I want to extract 70% of characters.

I am using :
**substring(Name,1, (length(Name)-5))**

But this does not work when length(name) is less than 2 or 3

Comment: Your current code doesn't extract 70% either..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```sql
SELECT Name, ID, SUBSTRING(Name, 1, CAST(CEIL(0.7*LENGTH(Name)) AS INT64)) AS Name70Pct
FROM yourTable;
```

Here we are taking 70% of the length of the name.  I wrap with `CEIL()` to ensure that a name of one character will at least return that one character.

Comment: It gives error : No matching signature for function SUBSTRING for argument types: STRING, INT64,FLOAT64

Comment: Try adding a cast to int to the 3rd parameter of `SUBSTRING()`.